# UITableView cannot scroll

Tags: scroll, uitableview

I have a tab bar, and two of the tabBarController.viewControllers has tableview inside.

When I launch the App. tab 1's tableview cannot scroll. When switch to tab 2 and switch back to tab 1. the tab 1's tableview can scroll.

So strange! Can anyone give a hint?

Is it related to number of rows? p.s. both of tableviews' frame is not filled with enough rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the tableView bounce? It should do this regardless of the number of rows.

Sounds like a problem with the bounds of the tableviews superview - if you set clipToBounds on the superview and the tableview disappears, then thats it.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I need to set tableView.bounces=YES(even it is already YES in XIB).  I configured other properties of the tableView in viewDidLoad, and I guess that might cause the tableView.bounches=NO.